# Fractional Differential

Tags: calculus, differential

How would you take a fractional differential. Such that $f^n(x)=3x^2+5x-4$ where $n=1/2$. I have been told that this could be done; however, when I try and figure it out I am not coming up with a reasonable answer.

Comment: [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Nature_of_the_fractional_derivative) might be what you are looking for. In your case, i.e. a polynomial, one has the natural solution by analytic continuation of the factorial that arises in the $n$-th derivative formula.

Comment: You might also be interested in the Gamma function. (It basically lets you take the factorial of non-integers.)

Comment: I'm not sure that makes sense. The n indicates how many times you're doing something. How can you half calculate the slope?

Answer (score 2):

Because $\ f^{(n)}(x)= D^{n}f(x)$, where $\ D=d/dx$,

and
$$\ D^{n}f(x) = 
\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-n)}\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{(x-t)^n} dt, 0<n<1$$

hence
$$
f^{(0.5)}(x)= 
\frac{1}{\Gamma(0.5)}\frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x \frac{3t^2+5t−4}{\sqrt{x-t}} dt$$
$$
 \Rightarrow f^{(0.5)}(x)= 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{d}{dx} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{4}{15}(12x^{2.5}+25x^{1.5}-30x^{0.5})\end{bmatrix}$$
$$
 \Rightarrow f^{(0.5)}(x)= 
\frac{8x^{1.5}+10x^{0.5}-4x^{-0.5}}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$